# wrapfig not working with llncs

Tags: wrapfigure, includegraphics

I am trying to split a single column page to double column such that figure appears on the left half and text appears on the right half.  I try to achieve it using wrapfig

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{Exp}
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \includegraphics[height=0.32\textheight]{mg.pdf} \\
            \includegraphics[height=0.32\textheight]{md.pdf} \\
            \includegraphics[height=0.32\textheight]{mc.pdf}
        \end{tabular}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

But it is not working.  My figure appears in a different page.

What can I do to split the text area into two vertical half such that text and image can be placed side by side.

UPDATE:  My document has to be single column, but it is ok that one page in the document to be two column, if possible. Or else I want to wrap the figures and text.

Comment: If you want two-column document, you have to give `twocolumn` option in `\documentclass`. But this gives the figures on right column.

Comment: @ferahfeza I can not do that. M document has to be single column. But I want just one page in that document to be two column or wrap the figures and text.   btw, the above code does not wrap the text.  text appears in different page and graphics in different page.

Comment: Just one page? Other pages in single column?

Comment: Yes. if it is possible. Else, wrap the text around the graphics.  The code above I pasted is not wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapfig is generally intended to accept one figure at a time. It becomes troublesome  when the envelope is pushed to three high. This was tested as working with PdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX. If you want to make alterations then do so in small steps.

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}

\begin{document}
\section{Exp}

\begin{wrapfigure}[39]{l}[0pt]{0.5\textwidth}\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\centering%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}\newline%
Fig1a\\%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}\newline%
Fig1b\\%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}\newline%
Fig1c\\%
}\end{wrapfigure}

\textbf{Hello this the first line of text and we should use a real example for certainty, since if we just use} \lipsum[1] fkokpmk \lipsum[2]lkopikml, \textbf{then we may have problems.}

\end{document}
```